# I need Selenium to open it's web browser in a larger resolution ( preferably maximized)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver and coding in Python

I have looked all over the place and the best I could find were things written in different languages. I also tried to use the export tool on Selenium IDE but when I look at the data says that the function is not supported for export.

EDIT:  The reason I need the browser to open up with a larger resolution is because the web application that I am testing is supporting tablet resolution as so elements are different depending on the resolution of the browser window.

This is the script I exported from the IDE with a couple of modifications.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

import unittest, time, re

from Funk_Lib import RS


class CreatingEditingDeletingVault(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "http://cimdev-qa40/"
        self.verificationErrors = []


    def test_creating_editing_deleting_vault(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/Login?contoller=Home")
        driver.find_element_by_id("UserName").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("UserName").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("UserName").send_keys("user@gocodigo.com")
        driver.find_element_by_name("Password").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("Password").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("Password").send_keys("Codigo#123")
        driver.find_element_by_id("fat-btn").click()
        driver.get(self.base_url + "/Content/Vaults/")
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Content").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Vaults").click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.dropdown-toggle").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("New vault").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("Name").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("Name").send_keys("Test Vault")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick=\"vault_action('createvault', null, $('#CreateVault [name=\\'Name\\']').val())\"]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.dropdown-toggle").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Rename vault").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("Id").click()
        Select(driver.find_element_by_name("Id")).select_by_visible_text("Test Vault")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("option[value=\"2\"]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("Name").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_name("Name").send_keys("Test Change")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick=\"vault_action('renamevault', $('#RenameVault [name=\\'Id\\']').val(), $('#RenameVault [name=\\'Name\\']').val())\"]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.btn.dropdown-toggle").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Delete vault").click()
        driver.find_element_by_name("Id").click()
        Select(driver.find_element_by_name("Id")).select_by_visible_text("Test Change")
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector("option[value=\"2\"]").click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@onclick=\"vault_action('deletevault', $('#DeleteVault [name=\\'Id\\']').val(), '')\"]").click()

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException, e: return False
        return True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: What have you found when you "looked all over the place"?

Comment: Provided it is written against Selenium bindings for whatever language it is in, it should be relatively painless to translate the examples in to the Python bindings.  I would caution against using static window sizes or maximization though, as it largely binds you to the specific machine and browser you are creating the tests in.  I forget which calls they are, but I believe Selenium has some sort of 'scroll element in to view' call, which would probably be the best choice for something like this.

Comment: I don't think something like what you're asking is really possible. Or, more accurately, it's very platform-dependent.

Comment: @user1854271 Are you asking how to set width and height in pixels (TONy.W has the right answer), or to set the display's DotsPerInch/PixelsPerInch?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Selenium 2.31.0

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Resize the window to the screen width/height
driver.set_window_size(300, 500)

# Move the window to position x/y
driver.set_window_position(200, 200)
```

Answer (score 26):

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://www.google.com/'
browser.get(url)
browser.maximize_window()
```

Answer (score 5):

You can either use `selenium.windowMaxmize();` or if you want to run your test in some specific resolution,You can go with

`selenium.getEval("window.resizeTo(X, Y); window.moveTo(0,0);")`

Comment: Could I get a little more clarification on where do put this command. I am very new to selenium... and to python to boot.

Comment: After creating your driver you can create object with WebdriverBackedSelenium which will give you access to selenium RC functions then you can use these functions in your code.
If you dont want to use webdriverbackedselenium then you can do it with driver.manage.window.resize_to(X, Y).

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking to increase the screen magnification?

This will magnify a Firefox browser, Python 2.7

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys    

br = webdriver.Firefox()
zoomAction = ActionChains(br)
body = br.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
for i in range(2):
    zoomAction.send_keys_to_element(body,Keys.CONTROL,"+").perform()
```

Comment: Thank you, I checked many answers, but yours was the only one working with Selenium 2.53 and Firefox.
I use  this now here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39248128/selenium-2-53-scolls-to-far-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-python-firefox