# Set browser window size in a step

Tags: selenium, bdd, lettuce

Im trying to write tests for a responsive website, and I want to write a step like so:

```
Given I am in the desktop view
```

or

```
Given I am in the mobile view
```

How can I accomplish this in lettuce?

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15417185/285614), but I cant figure out where to plug this, or if this is the best thing to do. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I finally accomplished this:

```
SCREEN_SIZES = {
    "desktop": (1020, 768),
    "tablet": (768, 1024),
    "mobile": (320, 460)
}

@step(ur'I am in the "(?P<breakpoint>(desktop|tablet|mobile))" view')
def set_viewport(step, breakpoint):
    """ Changes the resolution of the window """
    # Set the window size
    world.browser.driver.set_window_size(*SCREEN_SIZES[breakpoint])
```