# Title bar appears in middle of page during screenshots on Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, python-imaging-library

See below where I try to screenshot Facebook. The top bar which is normally at the top of the browser, is appearing in the middle of the screenshot.

How can I hide it, or adjust the browser so that the top bar stays up and out of the way?

I use Selenium to screenshot then I sent it to PIL to get it cropped.

Note that when this appears, I may be scrolled down quite a ways.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your code? The Selenium test?

Comment: Im able to take a screenshot with the top bar where it is supposed to be. I had a minimized browser.

Comment: @Striker Note that when this appears, I may be scrolled down quite a ways.

Comment: Got this issue. I might have a solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can manipulate the html code like deleting the class attribute of the navigation bar by this `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('blueBarNAXAnchor').setAttribute('class', '')")` then it stay in the begining of the page without style. Then you can take screenshot without it. See the below, check face_1.png:

```
>>> driver.save_screenshot("face.png")
True
>>> driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('blueBarNAXAnchor').setAttribute('class', '')")
>>> driver.save_screenshot("face_1.png")
True
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Possibly it has to do with the fact that the browser wasn't opened with maximum size.

Try calling `driver.maximize_window()` once at initialization before using `driver.get` and `driver.save_screenshot`.

Comment: Wasn't me, but I did set it to (1366, 768). Is that not enough?

Comment: It could be some screensize issue, hence I figured maximizing and allowing high resolution / different resolution could help?

Comment: It could be some *unfortunate* screensize issue

Answer (score 2):

Instead of increasing the window size your should `reduce` the window size. Set the window **height to less than 500px** and the top bar gets placed in the screenshot where it should be.

This is because when the browser height is below 500px, the top bar disappears from view. Above this height the top bar appears in the browser view port hovering over the news feed. You can try this manually too.

**JAVA**

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 500));
```

**PYTHON**

```
driver.set_window_size(300, 500)
```

The above code is in JAVA. But I believe that you can figure out the python equivalent.

NOTE : I have a screen resolution of 1366x768. So the value 500px might vary. But you certainly have to reduce the height.

Comment: Okay, so Basically make the window size a bit smaller than the screen size? I'm using a virtual display (Xvfb), so I can adjust everything.

Comment: No need of adjusting the virtual display. Just resize the browser size (reduce the height). The Java Selenium code posted above does that. I will try and update the python code required.

Comment: Python code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571349/i-need-selenium-to-open-its-web-browser-in-a-larger-resolution-preferably-max   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397483/how-do-i-set-browser-width-and-height-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I just noticed, I don't even set the window size. I only set the virtual display size.

Comment: By default the browser opens in a particular size even if you dont set it. You would have to override the default size

Comment: What about if I'm emulating mobile website versions with mobile screen sizes? I haven't checked if I have the problem there too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93307/discussion-between-striker-and-user).