# Selenium 2.53 scrolls too far - Element is not clickable at point - Python Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

When I call the click method, Selenium scrolls to far down so element is no longer visible.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.simplelogistik.de/")

element = driver.find_element_by_name("plz_sender")
element.send_keys("04357")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("plz_target")
element.send_keys("10249")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("length")
element.send_keys("123")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("width")
element.send_keys("12")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("height")
element.send_keys("34")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("weight")
element.send_keys("5,6")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='submit'][@class='btn btn-lg btn-product right']")
element.click()

element = driver.find_element_by_id("price-dpd")
element.click()
```

So temporarily I use a hack to zoom out:

```
Action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)   
body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
for i in range(2):
    Action.send_keys_to_element(body,Keys.CONTROL,"-").perform()
```

edit:
Before I call the click method the element it displayed. Also tried the "move_to_element" and wait.

```
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
if element.is_displayed():
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "price-dpd"))).click()
```

Comment: I dont know selenium python, but there should be Action method like `moveToElement`. Did you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I tried this already. And visible is True. But then It moves with the clicked method I think. I update question, Thank you.

Comment: `webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)` needs probably `perform()` method. You can also change "waitForElementVisible" to "waitForElementClickable" (I'm sorry, I dont know exact python commands)